# How to capture youtube iframe api event in React

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube, react-hooks, postmessage

I use iframe to import youtube embed url

```
<iframe
          id="ytVideo"
          src={embed_url}
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;"
 ></iframe>
```

And then I want to listen to the event when the youtube video onPlay and onPause

therefor I set a `window.addEventListener` on useEffect to get the iframe's postMessage event `onStateChange event`

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("message", event => {
      console.log("event", event.data);
    });
    return () => {};
  }, []);
```

But there isn't any capture when I play the youtube video.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way that google recommends you set this up. It involves setting up a YT.Player object.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `react-lite-youtube-embed` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lite-youtube-embed) for embedding the video, but you can use this same method for any other iframe:

From the YT API Iframe documentation: [Use Youtube API with existing `<iframe>`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors):

1. Set the `enablejsapi` parameter to `1`.
2. Wait for the iframe to be loaded after user plays the video, `onIframeAdded` will be triggered.
3. Call the `loadYtPlayer` as the `onIframeAdded` callback: the code in this section loads the IFrame Player API JavaScript code. We don’t make any server request unless the user asks for it, this way the page renders way faster. (Note that you can load it directly  in componentDidMount event in React in case you prefer it)
4. Setup the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function that will execute as soon as the player API code downloads. This portion of the code defines a global variable, `player`, which refers to the video player we are embedding, and the function then constructs the video player object.
5. The API will call the `onPlayerStateChange` function when the player's state changes, which may indicate that the player is playing, paused, finished, and so forth.

This is how I created the YoutubePlayer React component:

```js
import LiteYouTubeEmbed from 'react-lite-youtube-embed'
import 'react-lite-youtube-embed/dist/LiteYouTubeEmbed.css'
import { useRef } from 'react'

let player: { getCurrentTime: () => any }
let loadYtIframeAPI: Promise<any>

const YoutubePlayer = ({
  videoId,
  title,
  thumbnail,
}: {
  title: string
  videoId: string
  thumbnail: any
}) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null)

  const loadYtPlayer = () => {
    if (!loadYtIframeAPI) {
      loadYtIframeAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const tag = document.createElement('script')
        tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'
        const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
        firstScriptTag.parentNode?.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag)
        ;(window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () =>
          resolve((window as any).YT)
      })
    }

    if (videoRef?.current) {
      loadYtIframeAPI.then((YT: any) => {
        player = new YT.Player(videoRef.current, {
          events: {
            onReady: onPlayerReady,
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange,
          },
        })
      })
    }
  }

  const onPlayerReady = (event: any) => {
    console.log('onPlayerReady event', event)
  }

  const onPlayerStateChange = (newState: { data: number }) => {
    if (newState.data == 1) {
      console.log('Video Playing')
    } else if (newState.data == 0) {
      console.log('Video Finished')
    } else if (newState.data == 2) {
      console.log('Video Paused', Math.round(player.getCurrentTime()))
    }
  }

  if (videoId) {
    return (
      <div className="aspect-video">
        <LiteYouTubeEmbed
          ref={videoRef}
          wrapperClass="yt-lite rounded-md"
          id={videoId}
          title={title}
          thumbnail={thumbnail}
          params="enablejsapi=1"
          onIframeAdded={loadYtPlayer}
        />
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

export default YoutubePlayer
```